Not sure if this photo was tampered with
I have a picture and I'm not sure if it went through an app or what, but the resolution is horrible. I would like to know a bit more about it, but I am super out of my field with this one.
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.92
File Name                       : photo.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 100 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2024:08:28 13:13:58-04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2024:08:28 13:13:58-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2024:08:28 13:14:00-04:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)c
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Profile CMM Type                : 
Profile Version                 : 4.3.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2016:01:01 00:00:00
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Unknown ()
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : 
Device Model                    : 
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Media-Relative Colorimetric
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : 
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Description             : sRGB
Red Matrix Column               : 0.43607 0.22249 0.01392
Green Matrix Column             : 0.38515 0.71687 0.09708
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.14307 0.06061 0.7141
Media White Point               : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 40 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 40 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 40 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Profile Copyright               : Google Inc. 2016
Image Width                     : 750
Image Height                    : 339
Encoding Process                : Progressive DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 750x339
Megapixels                      : 0.254

There are some things that make my wonder, because of this sections:
Megapixels                      : 0.254
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)

Is there a way to know what kind of device took the picture, or if it was shared using some app like WhatsaApp? Because it seems curious to me that this picture, a screenshot, has a resolution of just 750 x 339
Thanks!

What's the real problem here? Why can't you just ask the person who provided you with the image?

I actually really don't think this is a photography problem per se.

I found the picture on a news site. So I can't really ask anyone the original.
Mmm and I guess you are right, it isn't a problem with photography per se. But I thought that establishing the tags as "image-quality", "exiftool" and "forensics" would help people note that.

It could have been scaled down, which isn't really "tampering", 750x339 is coherent with the aspect ratio of smartphone screens. But yes, when you share a picture it is very often scaled down or butchered in some way by the sharing application. For the rest, if  the info is not in the EXIF (also often cleaned up by sharing apps for privacy purposes) , it is difficult to infer from the image directly. The color profile by Google may hint that this was taken on an Android phone.

Thanks a lot for the comment. It actually helps. Thanks!

If the image is a screen capture, the exif is not that of the original image. It is the exif of the image created by the screen capture program (OS).
And the image resolution will be that at which it was being displayed when captured.
There is nothing of the original image to be evaluated...

Using exiftool, you should always use the command listed in exiftool FAQ #3. That will tell you where the tags you are looking at are located, as well as any tags with duplicate names.
Using that command you would see that Megapixels is a Composite tag and ExifByteOrder is a File tag, listed on the Extra Tags page.
Composite tags don't exist in the file. They are created by exiftool on the fly by combine other tags, usually to make it easier to understand or to copy. In the case of Megapixels, exiftool is simply multiplying the image width by height.
Tags in the File, with a couple exceptions, are usually properties of the file. The EXIF spec allows EXIF data to be written as either Big Endian or Little Endian (see Endianness-Wikipedia). The ExifByteOrder is simply stating how the EXIF data was written.
Some of the other tags in the file indicate that it has an ICC_Profile (see the ICC_Profile tags page), which is color data describing how it should appear on a screen or in print. An ICC_Profile is rarely, if every, inserted directly from a camera, though it is usually included in images from a scanner. It is also added by programs such as Lightroom and Photoshop.
So this image is quite likely been run through a program such as Photoshop/Lightroom, which would be quite likely from any professional photographer. Other than that, most of the data here is either file properties or the ICC_Profile. There is an EXIF block, but the only EXIF tag listed is the Orientation, which indicates how the image must be rotated to be properly displayed.
